# Conceptual question about change of energy in a Thermodynamic cycle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

[image]

For any thermodynamic cycle, net heat transfer must equal the work done. When the cycle is completed the system returns to its original state and so there is no change in energy. 
However, in the example problem shown, the work done is 540 kJ/kg but the heat transfer between the turbine and the surroundings is not equal to this value. Is this because at the time in consideration the system has not returned to its original state and will do so eventually?  [image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ChetMiller I could be wrong, but I think the question is the text underneath the Figure number.

Comment: My question is whether the system eventually, spontaneously returns to its original state at which time the net heat transfer will equal the work done

Comment: @user436788 Curious how they got h1=3230.9. My superheat table shows 2152.8.

Comment: @BobD Thanks Bob.  I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing this flow process, involving an open system (control volume), with a cyclic process carried out in a closed system.  The turbine is not operating in a cycle (although it is at steady state).  The authors are using the open system (control volume) versions of the first and 2nd laws of thermodynamics to solve this steady state problem.  If you are unfamiliar with the open system versions of the laws, you need to go back and review.  See Chapter 4 and Section 6.9 in your textbook for the details of these developments.

Comment: Just curious, but how did you know what textbook the OP is using?

Comment: @BobD In my judgment, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al is a wonderful thermodynamics textbook, and I am very familiar with this book.  I immediately recognized the kind of figures and style, and the structure of the solution methodology they are advocating.  Every problem is attacked in the same methodical way.

Comment: Sounds like it's worth getting a copy. I'll check into it. Thanks.